# GPS service close block screen

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a service which is closed and locked whenever the screen of my device or when it suspends, my question is
is there any way of my service not close even if the screen is locked or if the device suspend alone or even if you use some application that makes searching for GPS.
I thank you

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service
{
private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);            
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
} 
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
} 
private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use PowerManager PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK it works even if the screen is turned off

I tried something like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    // Put here YOUR code.

    Intent startAutoSyncService = new Intent(this,
            MyService.class);
    this.startService(startAutoSyncService);

    wl.release();

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering,when I press the home button and lock screen it keeps killing my service even adding wake look.
Have any solution?
Thanks again.